# Monitor "No Signal" after the Raspbeprry Pi logo

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot-issues

I installed RPi OS successfully on my RPi3 Model B, after couple of minutes the screen goes black and says "no signal". I am using a VGA monitor with a HDMI/VGA connector. When I reboot my pi using ssh, the Monitor shows output but it gets back to "no signal" after the Raspberry Pi logo.

**Update** with info from a comment:
When i first boot my pi after the installation of Raspbian, it was able to proceed to the desktop but after a couple of minutes, the screen suddenly goes black and says "no signal", i tried rebooting my pi and now it wont proceed to the desktop because after the raspberry pi logo the screen goes black again,

Comment: On the command line, if you hit every minute the "Enter" key with prompt output to the screen, does the screen also goes black then?

Comment: I cannot go to the command line because the monitor says "no signal" after the raspberry pi logo

Comment: I do not understand your comment in conjunction with the question. There you wrote: "***after couple of minutes** the screen goes black and says "no signal"*". Hit "Enter" in the first minute:

Comment: When i first boot my pi after the installation of Raspbian, it was able to proceed to the desktop but after a couple of minutes, the screen suddenly goes black and says "no signal", i tried rebooting my pi and now it wont proceed to the desktop because after the raspberry pi logo the screen goes black again, sorry for the bad english... I am new to this forum